# Laravel 5.6 Nesting Eloquent Relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

Good morning, I am currently learning Model relationship working on a gaming related project, I have a Bank Model with an hasMany relationship with the Transaction Model

```php
Schema::create('banks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name',30);
        $table->string('faction',10);
        $table->string('region',3);
        $table->integer('balance')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

Model is:

```php
class Bank extends Model
{
   use SoftDeletes;

   /**
   * Establishes a oneToMany relationship with the Transaction
   * model
   *
   * @param
   * @return
   */
   public function transactions()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction');
   }
}
```

Transaction Schema is:

```php
Schema::create('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('bank_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('operator_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('operation', 128);
        $table->integer('amount');
        $table->string('note',255)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();

        $table->foreign('bank_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('banks')
              ->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->foreign('user_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('users')
              ->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->foreign('operator_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('users')
              ->onUpdate('cascade');

    });
```

User schema is:

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Transaction Model is:

```php
class Transaction extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;

public function banks()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Bank');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
}
```

I would like to achieve in Laravel the following SQL:

```php
SELECT t.amount, t.created_at, b.name, b.region, b.faction, u.name 
FROM transactions as t
JOIN users as u
JOIN banks as b ON t.bank_id = b.id
WHERE b.id =1
ORDER by t.created_at DESC
```

I managed to write this that returns all the transactions from the selected bank, in this case 1 (but it's eventually passed via parameter)

```php
public function show($bank)
{
    $transactions = Bank::find($bank)->transactions()
                                     ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
                                     ->get();
    dd($transactions);
}
```

But I have no clue how to also retrieve the rest of my SQL.
Any help is appreciated with a bit of explanation.

Uploading the screenshot of the Json of this DD:
[Json](https://gyazo.com/3c73d3b34daf5e6c8c3af02b69b7d069)

How can I retrieve the field user.name of those two user_id and operator_id in the attributes? with Eloquent, not qBuilder

Comment: Just an observation, since both your `users` and `banks` relationships are `belongsTo` I would suggest renaming them to be `user` and `bank` as `belongsTo` relationships will only ever return one row.

Comment: $transactions = Transaction::with(['user', 'bank'])
                                    ->where('bank_id',1)
                                    ->limit(10)
                                    ->get();
        //dd($transactions);

Comment: You would need to update the method names in your Eloquent model as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the code with this:

```
$transactions = Transaction::with(['user', 'bank'])
                                ->where('bank_id',1)
                                ->limit(10)
                                ->get();
    //dd($transactions);
```

I also modified the Model Transaction relationship to:

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function bank()
       {
          return $this->belongsTo('App\Bank');
       }

    public function user()
       {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
       }
}
```

Since they return one model only.

Answer (score 0):

Put that method inside of Transaction model, it should be work

```
 public function getByBankId($id)
    {
        return $this
            ->join("banks as b", "b.id", "=", "transactions.bank_id")
            ->join("users as u", "u.id", "=", "transactions.user_id")
            ->where("b.id", $id)
            ->orderBy("transactions.created_at", "DESC")
            ->selectRaw("transactions.amount, t.created_at, b.name, b.region, b.faction, u.name")
            ->get();
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work: ` Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ RelationNotFoundException
Call to undefined relationship [users] on model [App\Bank].`

Comment: @FedericoBallarino ops sorry, you don't have relation with users in Bank model. I edited my answer

Comment: No this is not right, your 2nd answer does something different, what I want to retrieve is:
1) given a bank ID all the transactions that have that bank_id as foreign
2) on top of that every record of transactions has user_id record, and I want to retrieve the name of that user from the users table.

Comment: @FedericoBallarino Well, I changed little because, I really don't know which user you want to get ?

Comment: @FedericoBallarino I changed user section like `->join("users as u", "u.id", "=", "t.user_id")` does it works ?

Comment: It works but I was looking for something different :(

Comment: @FedericoBallarino is there any definition of that difference :)

Comment: I wanted to use the methods declared in the model Transaction, currently reading about eager loading at the moment...

Comment: @FedericoBallarino I edited my answer again, put that method on Transaction model

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a [`BelongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship:

```php
class Bank extends Model {
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'transactions')
            ->withPivot('amount')
            ->orderByDesc('transactions.created_at');
    }
}

foreach($bank->users as $user) {
    // $user->name
    // $user->pivot->amount
}
```

Comment: Exception
Property [users] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: `$bank` has to be a single instance, not a collection: `$bank = Bank::find($id);`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
$transactions = \App\Transaction::with('bank', 'user')
    ->where('bank_id', $bank)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

The `with()` method loads the relationships on to the model. You can then treat the relationships as properties to access information from them e.g.

```
foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {

    $transaction->amount;

    $transaction->user->name;

    $transaction->bank->name;
    $transaction->bank->region;

}
```

For more info please have a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Comment: I tried your solution, but it gives me an error:
https://gyazo.com/50c6a069e0c17260828cb23af0bb930c

Comment: @FedericoBallarino Do all of your transactions have a `bank_id` and `user_id`?

Comment: Yeah they do, I answered my question fixing the relations, thanks anyway

Comment: @FedericoBallarino Ah, I hadn't realised that you had changed the relationships from how you'd defined them in your question.

Comment: @FedericoBallarino No worries, glad I could help. I would suggest in the future to update your question if you ever change parts of your code 1) so that you can get your issue resolved more quickly and 2) so that it isn't confusing for anyone else who comes to the site looking for help with the same or similar issue.